# How to create a custom drawable Seekbar?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

For example I want my seekbar to look like on a pic below[image]

And I don't understand how to do it.

Should I draw it by hand or to program its shape I don't know where to start.

Can somebody explain how this works please.

Also maybe there are some type of data pack full of pre-made drawable files.

If you know something like that please let me know.

Comment: you can check this library https://github.com/smartSenseSolutions/SegmentedVerticalSeekBarDemo